# how to save input from e.get in a variable (python, tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm unsure if this has been asked (probably has), but I haven't seen anything from a quick google search. Sorry if this is a bad question as I'm a beginner python programmer.
I was wondering if it's possible to save information from an entry in python using tkinter with "e.get()"

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can directly save the value of `e.get()` in a variable by doing `any_variable = e.get()`.

Then you can use that variable for anything you want.

Hope my answer helped :D

Comment: It did help, I already figured this it just seems I was declaring my variable in the wrong spot so it didn't actually function. Thank you so much :)

Comment: no problem, but yes for next time, do keep in mind to add your code, what you have tried, and what problem you are facing in it, rather than just sending such and open-ended question. You're welcome to stack overflow :)